# Can Prestidigitation light a pipe?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cantrips

First, see 3.5/5e: [Should I allow Prestidigitation to ignite Grease (the game allows the Grease to be flammable)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47414/28926)

My plucky halfling likes the toke of a good pipe. I mostly use it for story fluff purposes only.

Can I use Prestidigitation to spark up in Pathfinder?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### No.

It specifically states in the prestidigitation spell:

> It can chill, warm, or flavor 1 pound of nonliving material.

So within the Rules as written for the Prestidigitation spell, no. It is unable to ignite tobacco. The spell you're looking for is [Spark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spark/).

Spark states:

> You can make an unattended Fine flammable object catch on fire. This
>   works as if you were using flint and steel except that you can use
>   spark in any sort of weather and it takes much less time to actually
>   ignite an object.

Comment: "unattended" - so technically you have to set the pipe down first?

Comment: Technically the tobacco is unattended.. inside the pipe. :P

Comment: I can't find a citation for Pathfinder, but at least in D&D, strictly speaking, "unattended" means it can't be held by (or in the space of) *another* creature. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/32225/what-does-the-condition-unattended-mean

Comment: Well the tobacco isn't being held by another creature in any case, it's being held by the pipe. :D

Comment: The intent of requiring unattended is that, one assumes, any attended item would be moved or have the spark swatted out before the ignition point - that is, to stop it being used as an attack. You wouldn't be attacking your pipe, tobacco, or self, so this should be OK, though that is of course a GM call.

Comment: @DewiMorgan "you wouldn't be attacking yourself.... " depends if its that wacky brain melting stuff from across the inner sea

Answer (score 14):

## The spell [*prestidigitation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prestidigitation) can light a pipe if one's willing to look to *Pathfinder*'s antecedent

*Pathfinder* is unable to use material from [*Tome and Blood*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786918454) (July 2001), one of the earliest *Dungeons & Dragons, Third Edition* supplements that was authored by *Third Edition* co-designer Skip Williams. In *Tome and Blood* in the section Fun with Prestidigitation, many common uses of the spell are detailed, including **firefinger**:

> You cause a jet of flame **up to** 1/2 foot long to shoot forth from your finger. The flame is hot and ignites combustible materials. Lighting a torch with this effect is a standard action (rather than a full-round action), but lighting any other fire with it takes at least a standard action (DM's discretion). (80)

(Emphasis mine.) One-and-a-half inches, I think, should be just about right for pipe-lighting.

The Wizards of the Coast Excerpts Web column ["*Tome and Blood: A Guidebook to Wizards and Sorcerers*"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20010707) includes the section Fun with Prestidigitation. (Readers can compare the *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* spell *prestidigitation* [here](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#prestidigitation) with the *Pathfinder* version [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prestidigitation); they're nearly identical.)

---

***Note:*** The Pathfinder *spell* [spark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spark/) *has a significant advantage over the firefinger use of the* prestidigitation *spell: the* spark *spell's range is 25 ft. +5 ft./2 levels compared to the* prestidigitation *spell's unchanging 10 ft.*

Comment: I think that Pathfinder created Spark to remove that feature from prestidigitation.  Mainly, i think, that became a 0th level spell that **everyone** had to have memorized.  Thus it was too powerful for its level.

Comment: @ShadoCat The spell *prestidigitation* is sometimes called *least wish* because the variety of tricks a caster can pull using it is limited only by the GM. Seriously, I think lighting a pipe should be among those tricks. The spell *spark* is — [as discussed in the other question's comments](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/108246/8610) — technically unable to even light a pipe! Also, jealous folks can get constant *prestidigitation* with the pretty-darn-cheap [*cloak of the hedge wizard*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-of-the-hedge-wizard/) anyway.

Comment: Since I knew a pipe smoker (my Dad finally gave up smoking), I realize that lighting a pipe requires a continuous flame for a couple of seconds but I'd still rather add that to Spark than let prestidigitation (I really hate typing that word) do **everything**.

Comment: @ShadoCat …And that's totally fair. I answered this question really only to add that the designers of the game from which *Pathfinder* stems did, in fact, intend the spell *prestidigitation* to be used to create fire capable of igniting a pipe. Like the answer says, *Pathfinder* doesn't (in fact, *couldn't*) *say* exactly what its earlier iteration said, so now any *Pathfinder* GM is welcome to run the ol' *p-dig* any way he or she wants. Personally, I'd totally let a dude light his pipe with *p-dig*, but I wouldn't flip the table and storm out if you told me my PC couldn't.